# Installing OneDrive

Tags: 20.04, package-management, software-installation, 22.04

This was simply a very stupid mistake on my part. Somehow I thought I had Ubuntu 22.04 and followed those instructions. I actually had 20.04.

---

I'm trying to install OneDrive following the instructions on https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md#distribution-ubuntu-2204 however I fail to complete the installation because

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests onedrive
```

returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 onedrive : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.12 is to be installed
            Depends: libphobos2-ldc-shared98 (>= 1:1.28.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to show held packages with

```
apt-mark showhold
```

it returns nothing.

```
sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
```

did not help.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

shows

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libass9 libgegl-0.4-0 protonvpn
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade libass9
```

which seemed to work but

```
sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade libgegl-0.4-0
```

did not. It returned

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgegl-0.4-0 : Depends: libopenexr23 but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

As per my response on GitHub, you have unfortunately followed the incorrect instructions for your operating system. From the error message:

- libc6 (2.31-0ubuntu9.12) (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/libc6) is for 'Focal'.
- libphobos2-ldc-shared98 (1:1.28.0-1ubuntu1) (https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libphobos2-ldc-shared98) is for 'Jammy'.

Focal is Ubuntu 20.x, Jammy is Ubuntu 22.x, thus the error message displayed hints that you followed the instructions for 'Jammy' (Ubuntu 22.x) rather than using the instructions for your actual Ubuntu version. This is why you cant install 'libphobos2-ldc-shared98' because it does not exist for 'Focal' and why you cannot install the application.

Please take care and follow the correct installation steps for your Ubuntu version to avoid errors like this.

Comment: Thanks! I was apparently an idiot. I was convinced I had 22.04 on this system and didn't even check (as you instructed to do and I should have done to be sure).